# Keypress event is not working properly

Tags: c#

I'm having problems with keypress events.

When I enter 10 digits in textbox1 it takes  10 digits as I want. But now if I press backspace it shows message "You can't enter more than ten digits". This is my first problem.

The second problem is that when I clear textbox1 pressing backspace and now enter digits again it takes only 9 digits.

Please tell me what's going wrong with my code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 9)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("You can't enter more than ten digits...");
      textBox1.MaxLength = 9;

  }
}
```

Comment: why are you changing the maxlength of the input box? 
at line 6      textBox1.MaxLength = 9;

Comment: You should check length in the keyup event, which is after keypress and keydown

Comment: It takes only 9 digits because you are settings text box max length ` textBox1.MaxLength = 9;` remove this one to avoid second problem.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy for your help . i am changing max length because in this text box i want a user to input only 10 digits. in this textbox user will enter his mobile no which i want in 10 digits so i am fixing maxlength to 9.

Comment: thanks Mirza Danish for your help. if i remove textbox maxlength it will take more than 10 digits which i don't want.

Comment: Mahaveer, change maxlength to 10 and instead of keypress, use keyup

Comment: maxlength=9 means it counts from 0 to 9 (10 digits).  if i set maxlength to 10 the textbox will count from 0 to 10(11 digits) and also not working with keyup event.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if KeyChar is backspace:

```
if (e.KeyChar != '\b' && textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 9)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("You can't enter more than ten digits...");
}
```

Comment: thanks this code helped a bit. first problem is solved but second one is as it was.

Comment: @Mahaveer have you removed this: *textBox1.MaxLength = 9;*? Also you should call this code in KeyPress event. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks Vano Maisuradze.  but have you read my code carefully. i have called keypress event. and if i remove maxlength , the textbox will take more than 10 digits which i don't want

Comment: Did you use e.Handled = true;?